# Creating a Provisioning Profile for my IOS App that will enable 3rd party to test my app

Tags: ios

I keep getting my App rejected by a 3rd party, (Nuance), because I evidently haven't been able to create a correct provisioning profile. Their install log says

"Application fails to install. Error says that a valid provisioning file was not found for this executable."

Now this is just a guess, but I'm thinking that when I create the provisioning profile, I am selecting the wrong App ID. The interface on the Apple developer site looks like this

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/index.action

I select the Distribution tab, and then New Profile. My doubt comes when I need to pick from the drop down list of App Id's it offers. Some of them are probably bogus, but without just serial guessing and submission, I don't definitively know which is the right one. Is there a way to verify my choice by looking in Xcode somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at your project target summary tab and check the bundle identifier.
Your app id should be created for that bundle (unless its with a wildcard).